# How to enable or disable check boxes based on a click event?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have a web app (PHP) and I have to make this change. I am more of a database, scripting guy, please bear with me on this one!

I have 8 check boxes (think numbered 1~8) in a form. I have to implement a condition where in :

> ```
> If one of the first 4 checkboxes are checked (only one checkbox can be checked in the first 4),
> Then the next 4 checkboxes should be disabled
> Else the next 4 checkboxes should be enabled.
> ```

My solution :

- Make the first 4 checkboxes radiobuttons to confirm to the **only one
  checkbox can be selected** condition.
- Disable/Enable the next 4 checkboxes based on the above action. So,
  if the radiobutton is not selected, then the next 4 checkboxes should
  be available for selection.

I have to actually disable the checkboxes rather than hide using jQuery, so the checkboxes should be solidgray (uncheckable) when disabled.

Sample code (stripped off some formatting mess for others looking for a similar solution) :

```
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="1" id="check1" <?php if (!empty($rows['check1'])) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
            <input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="1" id="check2" <?php if (!empty($rows['check2'])) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
            <input type="checkbox" name="check3" value="1" id="check3" <?php if (!empty($rows['check3'])) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
            <input type="checkbox" name="check4" value="1" id="check4" <?php if (!empty($rows['check4'])) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
            <input type="checkbox" name="check5" value="1" id="check5" <?php if (!empty($rows['check5'])) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
            <input type="checkbox" name="check6" value="1" id="check6" <?php if (!empty($rows['check6'])) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
            <input type="checkbox" name="check7" value="1" id="check7" <?php if (!empty($rows['check7'])) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
            <input type="checkbox" name="check8" value="1" id="check8" <?php if (!empty($rows['check8'])) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
        </div>
```

My requests :

- What is the most efficient way of doing this? (simple without complicating the problem)
- Any sample code is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hate to say this, but jQuery would be the easiest way. You can assign count 4 onClick events and then disable the not-selected checkboxes when you reach your desired count number.

Comment: after `id` you closed input tag, but you should open php `<?`

Comment: I would not switch to radio-buttons as they are impossible to turn off so that would only complicate things more.

Comment: @ Barlas : Editing it. Editor messed up those. @ Dainis : Can you please elaborate or post sample code? @ jeroen : I thought it is esier to use radio button but may be not! Thanks for the feedback. I will explore all checkbox solution.

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted! Moderators, please close the question if you think this doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.  You can achieve it using [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to get current clicked checkbox.  [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) is used to get all elements at index 4 and after.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    var $linputs =  $('input[type=checkbox]').slice(4);
    var $this = $(this);    
    $linputs.prop('disabled',($this.index() < 4 && this.checked));        
    if($this.index() < 4 && this.checked){
        $linputs.prop('checked',false);
    }
});​
```

[FIDDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/un5Tg/2/)

Or is it something like this that you want? Where only one of the first four checkboxes can be checked.  If one is checked then all the others will be disabled.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    var $this = $(this);    
    $(linputs).prop('disabled',($this.index() < 4 && this.checked));        
    if($this.index() < 4 && this.checked){
        $(linputs).prop('checked',false);
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h5wDr/

**EDIT:**

if you have other checkboxes in the page and want to be able to separate them from this logic, you can add context in the selector so it keeps this code isolated to only those within this div like so

```
<div id='test'>
                <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="1" id="check1" >first
            <input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="1" id="check2" >second
            <input type="checkbox" name="check3" value="1" id="check3" >third
            <input type="checkbox" name="check4" value="1" id="check4" >fourth
            <input type="checkbox" name="check5" value="1" id="check5" >fifth
            <input type="checkbox" name="check6" value="1" id="check6" >sixth
            <input type="checkbox" name="check7" value="1" id="check7" >seventh
            <input type="checkbox" name="check8" value="1" id="check8" >eight
</div>
```

Then just add the context

```
var $inputs = $('input[type=checkbox]', $('#test')); 
// this will only select checkboxes within the element with id=test
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h5wDr/2/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle sample! The problem is, only one of the first 4 can be checked (more like a radio button rule). And if one of the first 4 are checked, then the rest 5~8 are disabled.

Comment: @ThinkCode Check out my second fiddle.  I think that's what you want then

Comment: Wow, spot on! This works exactly the way I wanted. Thank you so much for such an easy to understand solution. Will you leave the fiddle solution on there for others to learn from this? I like the fiddle tool btw! Thanks again.

Comment: @ThinkCode Yes, I leave all my answers :)  and yw

Comment: I have other checkboxes in the form that shouldn't have this rule applied to. How do I isolate this rule to only these 8 checkboxes? Thank you!

Comment: @ThinkCode do you have a specific div with an id/class to separate them?  if so you can add the context inside the selector.  I'll add an updated answer to show you

Comment: Yeah, <div class="checkbox_div"> .

Comment: Oh ok. then just modify my update like this `var $inputs = $('input[type=checkbox]', $('div.checkbox_div'));`

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I plugged in your solution, the disabling of checkboxes only work when either the first or second checkbox are selected. jQuery is used in other instances of the page. There are other checkboxes as well but I thought the div id test should take care of only these checkboxes but apparently not. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: @ThinkCode can you show me your html structure in a fiddle?  It would help a lot with figuring out why there's still problems

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17077/discussion-between-thinkcode-and-wirey)

Answer (score 1):

```
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="1" id="check1" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="1" id="check2"  />
        <input type="checkbox" name="check3" value="1" id="check3"  />
        <input type="checkbox" name="check4" value="1" id="check4"  />
        <input type="checkbox" name="check5" value="1" id="check5"  />
        <input type="checkbox" name="check6" value="1" id="check6"  />
        <input type="checkbox" name="check7" value="1" id="check7"  />
        <input type="checkbox" name="check8" value="1" id="check8"  />
    </div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var $firstFourChecks = $("#check1,#check2,#check3,#check4");
        var $lastFourChecks = $("#check5,#check6,#check7,#check8");

        $firstFourChecks.on('click', function (e) {

            var isCheck = $(this).is(':checked');
            $firstFourChecks.not($(this)).prop('checked', false);
            $(this).prop('checked', isCheck);


            if (isCheck) {
                $lastFourChecks.prop("disabled", true).prop('checked', false);
            } else {
                $lastFourChecks.prop("disabled", false);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is entirely done in javascript, and is agnostic to the fact you are using php. Essentially, we make sure in the first four for you have not selected, they are set to false. Then we toggle the state of the one clicked.

If you clicked something on in your first four the last four are turned off and disabled, otherwise they are renabled. This matches the posted pseudocode.

You should be able to paste this directly in. The selectors are cached for speed reasons.

http://jsfiddle.net/L4qeN/ see it here.

Edit: wow looks like someone beat me to the punchline by only a few minutes. We did use very different methods; however.

Comment: This certainly is an improved version since I can toggle from the first 4 checkboxes! Let me see if it blends in with my PHP solution.

Comment: I hope it helps. Not sure if you can mark multiple answers as correct but i appreciate any rep as i am quite new and want to spend more time here helping others

Comment: Multiple answers not supported but your solution certainly works. Upvoted!

Comment: The script uses jQuery already. <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui/css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
........... I added your code in that block and now nothing is displayed in the page. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hey there, I see the references to jQuery ui, make sure you have jQuery referenced *before* jquery-ui. jQuery ui is a ui-extension to jQuery..it builds on top of it. So jQuery comes first, then jQuery ui

Answer (score 0):

You would have to try it yourself, but I would do something like (using javascript):

- Add a class to every checkbox of the first group and another class to every checkbox of the second group;
- Check for change events for the first class, turn off all of the first group but the clicked one;
- Check if any of the first group is selected and activate / deactivate the second class group accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Give your first four checkboxes one class and then your second four a second class and then add `onclick` handlers to all the first checkboxes:

```
$('.firstfour_class').click(
   if $('input:checkbox:checked.firstfour_class').length > 1){
       //code to turn OFF the second four and make them unchecked
   } else {
      //code to turn ON the second four
   }
})
```

[Check out the jQuery :checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).